# how to install slim tm bundle in sublime2

Tags: slim-lang

I would like to install the slim textmate bundle to sublime2. 
I went to this link
[slim textmate bundle](https://github.com/fredwu/ruby-slim-tmbundle)

I cloned it to the pristinepackage(as per the nettuts website) but nothing happened..
What am I missing?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's tempting to install by copying directories, you should really use the Sublime Package Manager.

[Install instructions are **super** easy](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) - just copy and paste.

After installing you can:

- browse other packages
- install packages within Sublime
- update packages easily

**One small hurdle to get over and Sublime becomes way more powerful.**

Comment: Honestly as that was like 8 months ago I no longer remember :)

Answer (score 34):

Try the following (it has worked for me):

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages
git clone https://github.com/slim-template/ruby-slim.tmbundle.git Ruby-Slim.tmbundle
```

And then in Sublime Text 2, you should be able to find 'Ruby Slim' in the bottom right language selection. At worst, you may need to quit and restart Sublime.

Comment: Heads up: Repo has been moved to git@github.com:slim-template/ruby-slim.tmbundle.git

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Mac OS with Sublime 3 you should use the Sublime 3 directory like this:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User
$ git clone git@github.com:slim-template/ruby-slim.tmbundle.git
```

PS: I tried to install syntax highlighting with the Sublime Package-Manager but it doesn´t work. Anyway, the two lines work for me. Maybe you should restart Sublime after cloning.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me also, however i had to add User/ like so

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/
git clone git://github.com/fredwu/ruby-slim-tmbundle.git Ruby-Slim.tmbundle
```