# No, really, how do you install the Ruby-Slim package in SublimeText2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I tried to follow the Ruby-Slim installation instructions provided in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946760/how-to-install-slim-tm-bundle-in-sublime2), but I don't know what to do now that I have downloaded a file or folder named 'Ruby-Slim.tmbundle' to the following location (Win7-64bit):

```
myname\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User.
```

This isn't the folder/directory spec'd in the Answers at the other link, but that directory path (Library/Application Support/) didn't exist, while this one had the rest of the specified path. At the same level as 'Packages\', there are 4 directories: Installed Packages, Packages, Pristine Packages, and Settings. Packages has all the folders, like 'Ruby', full of .sublime-snippet files.

So what do I do with this Ruby-Slim.tmbundle?

Comment: Thanks to the answer posted below. I'd followed those instructions (copy|paste large block of text and execute it, then restarted and...nada.

Comment: Thanks very much to the answer posted below. I'd followed those instructions, copy|paste large block of text and execute it, then restarted and...nada. 
It's that incredibly unintuitive need to got to 'Tools | Command Palette...' to then type in 'Package Control: Install Package'. I kept going to 'Preferences | Package Control' and then picking from that dropdown. But nothing popped up as a result of clicking on any of those choices. Now, however, after calling it from the ctrl+shft+p, that seems to have cleared its throat. The pop-up now lists php snippets  & the new Ruby-Slim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the linked question is the correct answer.  You don't personally download the package.  You install it through the package manager.  Forget about the folder you just download.

Go [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2)

Copy the large text that begins with `import urllib....` (this depends on which version of Sublime text you have).

Open Sublime text.  Open the console by pressing `ctrl + '` (this is a backtic)

Paste that massive amount of text into the console. Press Enter

Congrats, now you have package manager installed. Restart Sublime Text.

Use package manager to install Ruby-slim by pressing `ctrl + shift + p` and typing `"Package Control: Install Package"`  and in the next box type  `Ruby Slim`.  Select `Ruby Slim` from the options that come up and hit Enter and voila, you now have ruby slim installed.